# TeX question about double underlining in math mode

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to define a macro for double underline in TeX (not LaTeX).

Comment: The title and the body of your posting seem to contain some ambiguity: Is the double-underlining supposed to happen in text mode or math mode?

Comment: Well, for example, what are you trying to underline? A single symbol? A very long math expression?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 19):

The first idea that comes to mind is

```
\def\doubleunderline#1{\underline{\underline{#1}}}

$\doubleunderline{a+b}$

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: The `\underline{\underline{#1}}` has the "drawback" that the underlines of two consecutive underlined symbols merge, e.g. `$\doubleunderline{a}\doubleunderline{b}$`, which is often not what one would want in the context of writing matrices double underlined...

Comment: @Christoph90 Nobody should use double underlining to begin with. `;-)`

Comment: This also has the drawback of letting an awkward space between the two lines.