# Double underlining a result in a system of equations with calculation steps on the right side

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, arrays, underline

I am trying to create a system of equations with my calculation steps on the right side and a double underlined result.

I've decided to use `NiceArray` from the `nicematrix` package for the calculation steps, which has given me the intended outcome.

I guess there is a very simple way of underlining my result using `nicematrix`and `Tikz`. Unfortunately I have no experience with `Tikz`.

What do I have to write in order to double underline my result?

I was searching many hours for a solution to fix both of my problems (calculation steps and double underlining) and finally I think I am very close to the solution.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{NiceArray}{RCLL}
-2x + 72 & = & 18 - 7x  &\quad | - 7x \\
-9x + 72 & = & 18 & \quad | -72 \\
-9x & = & -54  & \quad | : (-9) \\
x & = & 6
\end{NiceArray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Under which row does this double underline occur, and what is its full left/right extent?  Welcome to the site.

Comment: Shhh.  I won't tell anyone, but the 2nd line does not follow mathematically from the first.

Comment: I suppose adding `\\\hline\hline` to the end of the `NiceArray` is not what you are looking for?

Comment: This looks like it might be what you were looking for

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249616/tex-question-about-double-underlining-in-math-mode

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\\\hline\hline` creates a line beneath the whole Array, which is not, what I suppose to do. @Benjamin Compson That answer creates a double underline but does not help me for my calculation steps, because I cannot use `\underline` for more than one column of the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd go with `array`, with a special purpose command:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\ssep}{\lvert\;}
\newcommand{\result}[2]{%
  \mathrlap{\underline{\underline{\mathstrut\hphantom{#1=#2}}}}%
  #1 & = & #2%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{r >{{}}c<{{}} l @{\quad} l}
-2x + 72 & = & 18 + 7x  & \ssep -7x \\
-9x + 72 & = & 18       & \ssep -72 \\
-9x & = & -54           & \ssep \mathbin{:}(-9) \\
\result{x}{6} \\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, with `aligned`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\ssep}{\lvert\;}
\newcommand{\result}[2]{%
  \mathrlap{\underline{\underline{\mathstrut\hphantom{#1=#2}}}}%
  #1 & = #2%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
-2x + 72 & = 18 + 7x  && \ssep -7x \\
-9x + 72 & = 18       && \ssep -72 \\
-9x      & = -54      && \ssep \mathbin{:}(-9) \\
\result{x}{6}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With a fancier highlighting:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}

\newcommand{\ssep}{\lvert\;}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
-2x + 72 & = 18 + 7x  && \ssep -7x \\
-9x + 72 & = 18       && \ssep -72 \\
-9x      & = -54      && \ssep \mathbin{:}(-9) \\
\tikzmarkin{r}x&=6\tikzmarkend{r}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: fancier]

Comment: Using aligned is by far the most simple way and works perfectly for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

with the `nicematrix` package (as you intended in your minimal working example -- *mwe*). lines for underline results are drawn with `tikz` added as `code-after` option of `NiceArray`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    \[\setlength\arraycolsep{1.2pt}  % <--- added
\begin{NiceArray}{RCLL}%
    [code-after={\tikz\draw[double, double distance=2pt, semithick]   % <--- added 
        ([yshift=-3]4-1.south west) -- ([yshift=-3]4-3.south east);}]
-2x + 72 & = & 18 - 7x  &\quad | - 7x \\
-9x + 72 & = & 18 & \quad | -72 \\
-9x      & = & -54  & \quad | : (-9) \\
x        & = & 6
\end{NiceArray}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

or fit box around result (again with use `tikz` as at above solution):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    \[\setlength\arraycolsep{1.2pt}    % <--- added
\begin{NiceArray}{RCLL}%
    [code-after={\tikz\node[draw=red, semithick, fit=(4-1) (4-3)] {};}] % <--- added
-2x + 72 & = & 18 - 7x  &\quad | - 7x \\
-9x + 72 & = & 18 & \quad | -72 \\
-9x      & = & -54  & \quad | : (-9) \\
x        & = & 6
\end{NiceArray}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]