# Two lines under e.g. Union symbol

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

How does one pile two lines under a union or intersection symbol in display mode? For example

`$\bigcup_{a,b \in \mathbb{R}; a+b=x} ... $`

displays everything in one line, as it should, but I would like to put those two statements one above the other. I'm sure it's been asked before and I apologise, but I just don't know what to look for.

Comment: Are you aware of `\substack`?

Comment: I guess I am now

Comment: Since you do not show a complete document I do not know what packages you are loading but maybe `$\bigcup_{\substack{a,b \in \mathbb{R}\\ a+b=x}} ... $` goes in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, I already managed once you basically told me to look up sub stack. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have taken like example this old question of @egreg [TeX question about double underlining in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249616/tex-question-about-double-underlining-in-math-mode)  and after I have added some other examples...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\def\doubleunderline#1{\underline{\underline{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\[ 
\doubleunderline{\bigcup}_{a,b \in \mathbb{R}; a+b=x} \ldots
\]
\[
\underset{=a,b \in \mathbb{R}; a+b=x}{\bigcup} \ldots
\]

\[\bigcup_{\substack{=a,b \in\, \mathbb{R}\\ a+b=x}} \ldots
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]